# how to listen data that sended from .net server in react page

Tags: .net, reactjs, payment

hi i want get data that sended from server in react. data sended as post metude from server and how can i get it in react js? is there any way? (i use react project and dotnet core server project  that they are in diffrent project and this problem happened when i wants Receive payment answer from bank)
i have PaymentResultSaman.js in react for show bank answer

```
class PaymentResultSaman extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      PreInvoice: {},
      loading: true
    };

  }
  loading = () => <Spinner color="primary" style={{ width: '5rem', height: '5rem' }} />

  componentDidMount() {

  }
  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading === false) {
      return (
        <div className="animated fadeIn">

        </div >
      );
    }
    else {
      return (<div style={{ marginRight: '480px', marginTop: '200px', marginBottom: '200px' }}>

        {this.loading()}
      </div>);
    }
  }
}
```

export default PaymentResultSaman;
thanks to read

Comment: I think most readers won't understand what you are trying to do. Could you clarify your question ? As an example, how do you get "Receive payment answer from bank" ? Maybe you are able to get some help with the English, too. It's a bit confusing (Sorry, I don't mean to be rude)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, no one understands me. After the bank payment operation, I send the information by post and I don't know How can I get the information that bank sends me by post metude in PaymentResultSaman  component in React

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to make your post request? Most libraries will allow you to use the async .then() method after a put or post request so that you can receive a piece of information from the server.

If you would like to receive an update from the server without having to make a put, post, or get request, then I think your only option is to look into using a web socket connection.

Comment: unfortunately, no one understands me. After the bank payment operation, I send the information by post and I don't know How can I get the information that bank sends me by post metude in PaymentResultSaman  component in React

Answer (score 0):

So you have three parts, your frontend code in React,
your backend in .NET Core,
and the banks API ?

And by post you mean HTTP Post method ?

I don't think your bank will Post anything to you.
So probably you need to do a POST or GET request towards the bank.
This can be done both from your client and from your server.
Your REQUEST will create a RESPONSE from the bank
Then you need to process the response.

You can't make you frontend wait for POSTs from the bank, or from your own server.

Maybe if you describe "bank payment operation" we will understand what you are trying to do.